# Server loads website each page load - session integrity is lost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, session, xdebug

To re-evaluate the title, if I go to `localhost/` in my browser, the page loads as you'd expect, loading any content I attempt to serve is done as I want, though I noticed something weird when debugging using **XDEBUG** (which is just a debugging software for PHP to watch what functions are called as well as loaded files) - There are two logs for the single load.

They'd load the entire Application two times over, as if the page the browser requested is loaded then the server decides to load it a second time, for fun!

This is the two log file I'm talking about when you load the page, analyzed using `Webgrind`.

[image: Image of XDEBUG log being managed from WEBGRIND]

The `.favicon` is Google Chrome trying to retrieve the favicon each load, which I understand would be loading the site a THIRD time, though I use an Illegal URL manager to stop the app from running when it sees the URI of `/favicon.ico`, so the app only runs twice now.

This is the `.htaccess` I'm currently using to manipulate URL's:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

My `access.log` from **apache**:

```
::1 - - [09/Jan/2017:23:57:27 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1597 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.51 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [09/Jan/2017:23:57:28 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1597 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.51 Safari/537.36"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's your actual page -- maybe you have a link to some resource (e.g. script, style or image) that has just `/` by mistake? As for `favicon.ico` -- just create such file to avoid errors (I guess it could be empty as well). What Chrome's Dev Tools/Network tab tells about that second request -- what initiates it?

Comment: Have you checked - maybe it's caused by URL rewrite somehow? You could try this instead: `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteBase /` `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` (sorry, no proper line breaks in the comments)
`

Comment: Actually I just noticed (**in the chrome dev tools**) - In the network area there's two `localhost`'s being loaded, and one's being initialized from `jQuery`, taking a better look into this... @LazyOne

Comment: Wow... @LazyOne - Just finished debugging and re-writing my library that I was using, and when the page loaded the index it'd load the `window.location.href` to act as a **"bookmark"**, which when set to nothing - was re-loading the page... 24 hours of debugging and was about to put a bounty on; I'm happy yet sad right now... How should I feel?

Comment: *"How should I feel?"* I'd say -- Happy: 1) mystery solved 2) new stuff was learned 3) some stuff was refreshed (the need of checking browser communications if they related to requests) which now will stay in your memory as "yellow sicker on monitor" and should save you some big time in other possible future cases :)

Comment: Thanks lots my friend :') I'm pretty happy I learned new stuff though. Made me bother to read the entire .htaccess documentation... so... thank you bug... Heavily appreciated :~) @LazyOne

Comment: I'd suggest to post your discoveries as an answer (and accept it later) -- will help a lot other users in similar situation. Accepted answer will: 1) make this question more visible 2) Will indicate that it was actually a solution etc.

Comment: Answered question @LazyOne, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I finished debugging my entire application (placing SESSION loggers at the index.php page to then revise the SESSION value later and see what's being requested) using the following code on my `index.php` page:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['logs']) $_SESSION['logs'] = [];

array_push($_SESSION['logs'], [
  'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
  'ua' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
  'uri' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
  'tim' => time()
]);
```

(View later using `print/echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION['logs']) ,"</pre>";`)

I could see all logs were the same besides the odd

```
'uri' => '/favicon.ico'
```

Indicating Google Chrome was requesting `favicon.ico` from my app, so I set up a temporary

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/favicon.ico') exit;
```

Just to block that request, and to try to get the logger down to one application load.

After limiting the requests down to 2 (both `localhost/`), I took a look into my `access.log` file, which showed two of the SAME request but one request was to `localhost/` and the other was to `-` (`-` = `undefined` to logging), so after 24 hours of debugging I remember that there's the Chrome Dev Tool which I had previously looked into which shows all network connections;

The Chrome Dev Tools showed two calls to `localhost` which I thought was strange, but the initiator was `jQuery` (at the time I didn't know a `$.get` AJAX request counted as a `jQuery` initiator, so I ignored looking into it, till recently I realised I have a method loading when the page is loaded, which will request the current `window.location.hash` in  GET

```
$.get( window.location.hash.substring(3), function(body) {} );
```

Which was requesting (when loading `localhost/`) ... `localhost/`, since there's no `hash` part of the page.

So this all came down to there being a autoloader, though I checked each `img` tag and `link rel` / `script` tag in the entire application (200k lines of code).

Hope this helps any of you! It took he a heap of time to figure this out.
(And sorry for the bad English it's 2am)